# Myriad Pro differences otf and latex

Tags: fonts

I was comparing some text and math from a latex document to those I get when I use a text editor (Apple Pages in my case) using the Myriad Pro font family. While the text looks exactly the same, the numbers don't
[image]

Left is the pages output and right the one from latex. I installed the MyriadPro via [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro). A MWE for the tex part:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[math]{MyriadPro}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
Some text, looks the same as the otf font.

$0.0$, does not look as the otf font.
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions why that is and if I could fix this?

Comment: Even if you remove the dollar signs?  I think there is another font loaded for numbers in math mode

Comment: @DaPhil - Try `\usepackage[math,lf]{MyriadPro}` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Arash Esbati That did it! Great!

Comment: For plain text, the lining figures (`lf` option) is what you want probably because is what you have always seen in word processors,  but IMHO old style figures is a more readable and elegant option.